# How to merge multiple queries into a single query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table called "productClick" like this:

```
----id------click-------------ctime----------
|    1  |    5     |   2015-12-26 00:01:12  |
---------------------------------------------
|    2  |    2     |   2015-12-27 00:01:12  |
---------------------------------------------
|    3  |    7     |   2015-12-28 00:01:12  |
---------------------------------------------
|    4  |    1     |   2015-12-28 00:01:12  |
---------------------------------------------
```

I want to get total number of product, **today's total number of product added** and sum of total click.

I have three separate queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalProduct FROM productClick
SELECT COUNT(*) as todayTotalProductAdded FROM productClick WHERE DATE(`ctime`) = CURDATE()
SELECT sum(click) as totalClick FROM productClick
```

It works fine. But I want to combine this three separate queries into one query. How to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Question updated. Sorry for my fault. Thanks **@Gordon Linoff**

Comment: Is `todayClick` really `COUNT(*)`?  Shouldn't it be `SUM(click)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalProduct,
       SUM(click) as totalClick,
       SUM(DATE(ctime) = CURDATE()) as todayClick
FROM productClick
```

The `todayClick` is shorthand for:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(ctime) = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as todayClick
```

or `UNION ALL` if you want multiple rows:

```
SELECT 'totalProduct' AS counter_name, COUNT(*) AS counter_value FROM productClick
UNION ALL
SELECT 'todayClick', COUNT(*) FROM productClick WHERE DATE(ctime) = CURDATE()
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'totalClick', SUM(click) FROM productClick
```

**EDIT:**

> today's total number of product added and sum of total click.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalProduct,
       SUM(click) as totalClick,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(ctime) = CURDATE() THEN click ELSE 0 END) as todayClick
FROM productClick
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks. But can you explain me this line SUM(DATE(ctime) = CURDATE())  ?

Comment: @AshisBiswas When `DATE(ctime) = CURDATE()` you get true or false. When summing it false is represented by 0 and true by 1. **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/37404/0)**. At the end it is just summing 1 and 0.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Got it. :)

Comment: I think using unions in your sql command can be more readable. Using boolean conditions inside sum, count, for instance, it only will sum or count when it's true. Consider sum 'null' for certain cases when 0 (zero) is a 'value'.

Comment: @CarlosA.Junior That's exactly the point of conditional aggregation. Null will be handled properly as in each query itselt. First query is COUNT(*) the same as OP, SUM(click) the same as OP, the same with todayClick. See I wrote boolean condtions as a shorthand. If you need different value or column use full `CASE WHEN`. Using UNION ALL over multiple columns depends on requirements. For counters I like one row with multiple values, but as always it depends.